# In NumPy, how to explain the return of ndarray[True]?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In NumPy, I know that we can index an `ndarray` by boolean values in the following way in a Python interpreter:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.arange(1, 6)
>>> print(b)
[1 2 3 4 5]
>>> bi = np.array([True, False, True, False, True])
>>> print(b[bi])
[1 3 5]
```

Then I tried `b[True]`, I couldn't understand what its return means. Could someone explain it to me? Thanks.

```
>>> print(b)
[1 2 3 4 5]
>>> b[True]
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
>>> b[True]
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

**EDIT**

With this feature, can I use it to get a vector from a rank one array? Just like the following:

```
>>> b = np.arange(1, 6)
>>> print(b)
[1 2 3 4 5]
>>> row_vec = b[True]
>>> print(row_vec)
[[1 2 3 4 5]]
>>> col_vec = b[True].T
>>> print(col_vec)
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]]
```

I have to say, it is hard to understand, but is it a better choice than `reshape` method to do that?

Comment: Another important [thing to read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)